# How to authenticate REST web service without displaying any login page or any JSP page in Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security

I want to integrate spring security in REST web services but when the url is hit default login page displayed by the Spring Security. How I can authenticate REST web service without any displaying any login page or any JSP page.

Comment: Look into certificate-based and key-based authentication modes. They allow a client to programmatically prove its identity to the server.

Comment: Return a `401 Unauthorized` and rely on the the client developer to post credentials to your login endpoint when necessary.

Comment: Which credentials will the client use? Username/Password -> basic authentication? Certificate? or will a third party access the user data -> oAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Spring security in your application, using `preAuthorization` in `@EnableGlobalSecurityMEthod ~`, I think is this annotation. In your restservice, using `@PreAuthorization("<role>")`, I think is this annotation. This works very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have basic authentication, then you can simply post username/password encoded in `Authorization` http header from client.

Or you can have [PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.html) configured with a pre-authentication [RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html)